# Celery 4 + Django 2.0 - CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS is ignored

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm using Django 2.0 with Celery 4 & SQS as a broker.

I used the following CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS:

`{'queue_name_prefix': 'qa-', 'region': 'eu-west-1'}`

I have:

1. Dedicated worker running using `celery -A <app_name> worker -Q <queue_name>`
2. Task with `@shared_task` decorator
3. Django web service that calls the task with `.delay()`.

The issue is that the worker is able to read the broker_transport_options, and it created a queue with the correct prefix in the correct region as I stated in the settings, but when the Django ignores these settings and push  the task to a queue without the given prefix and not in the correct region.

Does anyone know what is the case here?

Thanks,
Dar

Comment: I'm facing the same problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the namespace settings for your Celery conf is correctly set